# Vue - adding a Class-Name to a Component using a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to make a custom component in Vue with the following props:

- **text** = text to be displayed in the link.
- **icon** = identifier of the icon to be displayed next to the link.

> < sidebar-link text="Home" icon="fa-home">

I have the following .Vue template for my component.

```
<template>
    <div id="sidebarItem">  
        <a href="/index.php">
            <div id="sidebarIcon"><i :class="{fa : true}" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div id="sidebarText">{{ text }}</div>
        </a> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['text', 'icon'],
    data () {return {}}
}
</script>
```

Essentially I have the default Font-Awesome code in my template:

```
<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and I want add a class to my component by using it's prop.

```
<sidebar-link text="Home" icon="fa-home"></sidebar-link>
```

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean switch out? or what is your expected output?

Comment: poor choice of wording on my behalf. I'd like to be able to add a class-name to my component with a prop. So, if I wanted my component to show the Bluetooth icon, i'd switch the prop to " icon='fa-bluetooth' "

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So when your property `icon` is holding the value `home` you can use some class binding like the following (Thank god js expression are allowed within [attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) in Vue.js):

```
v-bind:class="[{'fa': true}, icon ? 'fa-' + icon : '']"
```

or even shorter

```
:class="[{'fa': true}, icon ? 'fa-' + icon : '']"
```

This will result in

```
class="fa fa-home"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to add `fa-home` to your  you can pass it on the parent component like:

```
<sidebar-link text="Home" :icon="'fa-home'"></sidebar-link>
```

You can pass other icons like `fa-plus`, `fa-blutooth` .... instead

And use it inside your component as:

```
<div id="sidebarIcon">
   <i class='fa' :class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

tbh: makes a little sense for me why you need to keep `fa`

You still need a prop maybe with default value of `''` though

```
icon: {
  type: String,
  required: false,
  default: ''
}
```